# Securing Eureka, Zuul in Spring cloud

Tags: spring-cloud

Can Spring cloud services like Eureka, zuul be secured by other than basic authentication? Instead of configuring like below (basic auth configuration), Is it possible to protect these services with token based mechanism (mostly a static token).

**Eureka service configuration**

```
security:
  basic:
    enabled: true
  user:
      name: username
      password: password
```

**Other services (register to eureka) configuration**

```
     
eureka:
  client:
    registerWithEureka: true
    fetchRegistry: true
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://username:password@localhost:8761/eureka/
```

Comment: Yes, see http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/Dalston.SR3/#_authenticating_with_the_eureka_server

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I will look into this.

Comment: I am able to successfully pass authorization token by creating a DiscoveryClientOptionalArgs bean and inject ClientFilter instances into it at EurekaClient end as mentioned in the doc. Thank you.